# springboot web request timeout setting

Tags: spring-boot, timeout, config

I wanna set a time to resolve a method cost too many time.
I try some config in `application.yml` but doesn't work. I hope it can return some err but it return "true"

```yaml
server:
  tomcat:
    connection-timeout: 1s

spring:
  mvc:
    async:
      request-timeout: 1s
```

this is my test controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TimeoutTest {


    @RequestMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
        try {
            System.out.println("start");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("end");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "true";
    }
}
```

how can I do？ and what's means about those tow doesn't work config？

Comment: You need to return a Callable<> if you want spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=5000 to work.

Answer (score 0):

Return a Callable<> for using spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=5000

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Callable<String> getResponse() throws InterruptedException {
    return new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            Thread.sleep(10000); 
            return "morgen";
        }
    };
}
```